# Git pull doesn't pull down recent commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a Git repo on BitBucket. I have two branches `master` and `db`. On my laptop I made changes to `db`, commited the changes and pushed up to BitBucket. I can see the commit in that branch.

Now I'm at my desktop at work and I've done a `git pull` whilst on branch master. It's pulled down master's commits but not db, which I guess might be the way it should work. I want to get the latest commits on db so I switch to that branch and do `git pull` however I get the following message:

> You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you want to merge
>   with...

I'm not really sure why this is happening. I created that branch on this machine so should it not just pull down the commits into that branch?

**OUTOUT FROM git branch -vva**

```
$ git branch -vva
  analytics             cea39b9 updated analytics code
* db                    6091b29 minor change to the tag creation code
  master                0a4070c [origin/master] Merge branch 'master' of https:/
/bitbucket.org/billyjones/findr.fm
  remotes/origin/db     faf9970 Got tracks working. Now trying to cache prices.
  remotes/origin/master 0a4070c Merge branch 'master' of https://bitbucket.org/b
illyjones/findr.fm
```

It's the faf9970 commit I need to pull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your desktop has not yet a local `db` branch, you first have to create it:

```
git branch db origin/db
```

It might be necessary to perform a `git fetch -a` before that.

If the local `db` branch already exists make sure that it tracks the corresponding remote branch.

You can verify that via `git remote show origin`. Under the heading "Local branches configured for 'git pull':" it should show "db merges with remote db". If that's not the case execute this command if you are on git 1.8:

```
git branch -u origin/db db
```

If you are on an older version of git, use this command:

```
git branch --set-upstream db origin/db
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, my desktop has the db branch. I created it on here and pushed it up, then pulled it to my laptop, then I pushed up to Bitbucket and now trying to pull new commits back down to my desktop

Comment: @iamjonesy: Alright. Your local branch seems not to be tracking the remote one. Please see the second part of my answer on how to fix that.

Comment: git remote show origin shows that only the master branch is configured for git pull. I tried the last command but get error: unknown switch 'u'

Comment: @iamjonesy: It looks like you are on a pre 1.8 version of git. Please see updated answer for a way in an older git version.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, now tracking remote chages for branch db. Thanks for your help